# Error al compilar Servidor Eureka

Tags: spring-boot, eureka

Esta es la salida

```
--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ eurekaServer ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 1 resource

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ eurekaServer ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ eurekaServer ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Carlos Diaz\Downloads\Proyecto\CompanyPadre\InfraEstructuraDominio\EurekaServer\src\test\resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ eurekaServer ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

<<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.4:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ eurekaServer <<<


--- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.4:run (default-cli) @ eurekaServer ---
Attaching agents: []
15:10:48.137 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@49d03aa0
15:10:48.831 [restartedMain] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - Application failed to start due to an exception
org.springframework.cloud.commons.ConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor$ImportException: No spring.config.import set
    at org.springframework.cloud.commons.ConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:297)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
    at com.example.eurekaServer.EurekaServerApplication.main(EurekaServerApplication.java:13)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
15:10:48.831 [restartedMain] ERROR org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

No spring.config.import property has been defined

Action:

Add a spring.config.import=configserver: property to your configuration.
    If configuration is not required add spring.config.import=optional:configserver: instead.
    To disable this check, set spring.cloud.config.enabled=false or 
    spring.cloud.config.import-check.enabled=false.
```

El main

```
    @EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class EurekaServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

El pon

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.infraestructuradominio</groupId>
        <artifactId>InfraEstructuraDominio</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>eurekaServer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>EurekaServer</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>    
    <dependencies>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>    
    <build>
        <plugins>   
            <!--Need on each project for build and executable jar or war and 
            construct a manifest-->      
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>     
                <!--                <version>${spring-boot-maven-plugin.version}</version>      -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>         
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

y el pom padre

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>Dominio</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.infraestructuradominio</groupId>
    <artifactId>InfraEstructuraDominio</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>EurekaServer</module>
    </modules>    
    <properties>
        <spring-cloud-dependencies.version>2021.0.0</spring-cloud-dependencies.version>
    </properties>
    
    <!--Allows consolidate and centralized management of deendency version witout adding dependencies
    that are inherit by all children, it is useesfull whe we have a set of porjects that inherit a common parent.-->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-dependencies.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>        
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Desde Spring Boot v2.4, ese parámetro es obligatorio y pide que le indiques si quieres obtener la configuración desde algún Config Cloud

```
spring:
  config:
    import: "optional:configserver:"
```

Nunca está de más revisar la [documentación oficial](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#config-data-import).

Ahí dice *en perfecto español* que, si dejas este valor que te muestro, por defecto usará la ubicación `http://localhost:8888`.

También dice que el prefijo `optional:` evita que falle si no logra conectarse y, si lo quitas, falla el despliegue.